# Did Uber, in its early startup days, hire engineers just by asking newly hired engineers "Who are the best engineers you've worked with"?

Tags: business

In a [2016 article, *Blitzscaling*](https://hbr.org/2016/04/blitzscaling), [Reid Hoffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reid_Hoffman) claims:

> In hiring, for instance, you may need to get as many warm bodies through the door as possible, as quickly as you can—while hiring quality employees and maintaining the company culture. How do you do that? Different companies use different hacks. As part of blitzscaling at Uber, managers would ask a newly hired engineer, “Who are the three best engineers you’ve worked with in your previous job?” And then they’d send those engineers offer letters. No interview. No reference checking. Just an offer letter. They’ve had to scale their engineering fast, and that’s a key technique that they’ve deployed.

I saw this claim posted on [Team Blind](http://www.teamblind.com) without reference. I tried searching on the web but found nothing but a Facebook post claiming the same thing.

Is this claim true?

Comment: I have read accounts similar to this, dating back 10-15 years.  Hard to tie to specific businesses, though.